# public variable cannot read by other function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

why my public variable cannot read by other function?

my public variable :

```
public $dataku = array();
```

first i set data to my public variable from model:

```
function cari() {

        $penerima = $this->input->post('penerima');
        $tanggal = $this->input->post('tanggal');
        $tanggal2 = $this->input->post('tanggal2');
        $id_komoditas = $this->input->post('id_komoditas');
        
        $this->dataku['judul'] = $this->judul;
        $this->dataku['pencarian'] = $this->mdl->get_data_antara_tanggal($penerima, $tanggal, $tanggal2, $id_komoditas);
        $this->dataku['url'] = $this->url;

        $title = "Data ".$this->judul;
        $subtitle = $this->url;
        $content = $this->load->view('cari.php', $this->dataku, true);

        $this->load_content($title, $subtitle, $content);
        
    }
```

but, when i want to read the public variable data again, it hasnt a data :

```
function check_data(){
        $data = isset($this->dataku['pencarian']) ? $this->dataku['pencarian'] : 'no data';
        print_r($data);
}
```

please, i need your help.

Comment: `$this->$dataku['pencarian'];` should be `$this->dataku['pencarian'];`. You don't add a `$` in front of property names of an instance.

Comment: `$dataku['pencarian'] = ...` should also be `$this->dataku['pencarian'] = ...` if you want to update the property and not just a local variable inside that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to access the class [properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) with `$this`. Change the following lines:

```
$this->dataku['judul'] = $this->judul;
$this->dataku['pencarian'] = $this->mdl->get_data_antara_tanggal($penerima, $tanggal, $tanggal2, $id_komoditas);
$this->dataku['url'] = $this->url;
```

Also edit the following (you have an extra $):

```
function check_data(){
    $data = isset($this->dataku['pencarian']) ? $this->dataku['pencarian'] : 'no data';
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: but i got error when i call it in the first function

Comment: which one is the first function?

Comment: it's because local variable `$dataku` doesn't exist, the class property `$this->dataku` exists. You can change the 3 lines I mentioned above and it should work.

Comment: hey, i'm sorry i'm not read carefully. cari function is work when i use, $this->dataku['pencarian'], but not work when i use function check_data()

Comment: thank you, but still get error Message: Undefined index: pencarian

Comment: this is a different error, the variable exists but the index doesn't

Comment: i dont know why pencarian cannot read when the first function i use is cari function, and then check_data() function

Comment: i've try this $data = isset($this->dataku['pencarian']) ? $this->dataku['pencarian'] : 'no data';, and the output is no data

Comment: this is because you didn't update your code with the first part of the answer I gave. change
$dataku['judul'] = $this->judul;
$dataku['pencarian'] = $this->mdl->get_data_antara_tanggal($penerima, $tanggal, $tanggal2, $id_komoditas);
$dataku['url'] = $this->url;

Comment: i 've try yours bro $this->dataku['judul'] = $this->judul;
$this->dataku['pencarian'] = $this->mdl->get_data_antara_tanggal($penerima, $tanggal, $tanggal2, $id_komoditas);
$this->dataku['url'] = $this->url;

Comment: maybe you can update your question to the current state of your code

Comment: and can you show how you are calling each method please?

Comment: first. i call method cari() to search data from input, and after that, in the next page, i have a button that call method check_data()

Comment: next page usually means a new PHP request and application lifecycle. This means any data stored in your class variable will be reset, as a new instance of the class is created

Comment: do you have any solution to get the data by the second method? because it in one controller. or you have solution to set data to a new instance?

Comment: you would need to store values to session, I would personally modify my application flow so I could show the response in the `cari` method

Comment: @RichardKyle I think my answer correctly addresses your initial question, maybe you can accept it please? Now you don't have undefined variable error

Comment: yes bro, thanks for you help. i have try using session and it works. thank you.